# Angular2 dynamic templating

Tags: templates, angular, inheritance

How do I use nested templates in angular2. So basically I have a base component and it's childs

```
- entry.component.ts
- entry.component.html
- navigation
-- sidenav.ts
-- sidenav.html
-route1
--route1.ts
--route1.html
```

entry.component.html should be a skeleton and the content should be generated dynamically on route changes.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean you ant to use a template and then show the components in the templates?

Comment: yes that would be the idea. Do not reuse multiple times template parts

Comment: Your requirement look like the basic behavior of routing, check the documentation, router-outlet is the key. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use templates with child routes.

I separate mine in `public` and `secure` routing everything through the layout then loading the routes for which ever layout is chosen.

Make sure to export the child routes and that the correct routes are called in the layout route. Also make sure you use `redirectTo` in each child routes file.

```
app.routing.ts

    const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
        { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full', },
        { path: '', component: PublicComponent, data: { title: 'Public Views' }, children: PUBLIC_ROUTES },
        { path: '', component: SecureComponent, canActivate: [Guard], data: { title: 'Secure Views' }, children: SECURE_ROUTES }
    ];
```

Then I have a layouts folder

**layouts**

```
layouts/public/public.components.ts
layouts/public/public.components.html
layouts/secure/secure.components.ts
layouts/secure/secure.components.html
```

**child routes**
**/public/piublic.routes.ts**

```
 export const PUBLIC_ROUTES: Routes = [
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path: 'p404', component: p404Component },
        { path: 'e500', component: e500Component },
        { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
        { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
        { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent }
    ];
```

**/secure/secure.routes.ts**

```
export const SECURE_ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'overview', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'items', component: ItemsComponent },
    { path: 'overview', component: OverviewComponent },
    { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent },


 { path: 'reports', component: ReportsComponent }
];
```

**Creating components to load into the template**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './benefits.component.html',
})
export class BenefitsComponent {

  constructor() { }

}
```

The create its html template,

```
/public/benefits.component.html'
```

Now that it is part of the public route. When someone goes to a public route it will be loaded in the chile routes. so inside your 
`/public/public.routes.ts` file you would add it for every new route you wanted to create to load your new `html` page.